# ASP.NET WebAPI - Where is the method which handles local login?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm reading about local login in asp.net web api in the following link.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api
However, when look at the following code which send user's logindata to server to authenticate user, I couldn't find out which is the default method in asp.net web api which handles the local login.
So, where is it actually ?

```
var loginData = {
grant_type: 'password',
username: self.loginEmail(),
password: self.loginPassword()
};

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/Token',
data: loginData
}).done(function (data) {
self.user(data.userName);
// Cache the access token in session storage.
sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
}).fail(showError);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I finally realized the url it was calling was /Token:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Token',  //!! plain as day !!!
        data: loginData
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.user(data.userName);
        // Cache the access token in session storage.
        sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
    }).fail(showError);
```

This which is setup to be associated with the ApplicationOAuthProvider in Startup.Auth.cs

```
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215672/in-web-api-owin-architecture-where-are-requests-to-token-handled) helped a lot.